# ReplacableToken_ when using web.config transform?

Tags: web-config

I have a web.config with 2 transforms - for debug and release.

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="StrName" connectionString="data source=.\sqlexpress;User Id=sa;Password=pass;Database=SocialBot;"
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I just copied the example given and replaced the name with StrName. I end up with :

```
<add name="StrName" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_SocialBotConnectionString-Web.config Connection String_0)"
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What the hell is ReplacableToken_ ?

I have another project and it works with no problem there.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If, like me, you're running up against this problem while trying to automate your build process using msbuild from the command line. Specifically, the parameter you need to set is:

```
/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False
```

This is most likely what VS is doing on your behalf when you publish to the filesystem

Answer (score 33):

If you want to build with Visual Studio 2010, add the following line to your configuration PropertyGroup in your .csproj:

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

More details here:
[How to get rid of "$(ReplacableToken...)" in web.config completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207689/how-to-get-rid-of-replacabletoken-in-web-config-conpletely/7586546#7586546)

Comment: +1 This is what allows you to click "Build Deployment Package" to get the transformed web.config.