# How to get rid of "$(ReplacableToken...)" in web.config completely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, web-config, publish

I am creating a publishable package and when I navigate to `obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp` directory, I am seeing the web.config's connection string is replaced by a replacable token, and I simply don't want that. I won't be using publishing batch files or anything, I'll be copying the files in the directory (I'm using the publishing package system only to get rid of lots of dynamically generated files while I'm testing my project and get the fresh/original file tree of my project) I don't want those web.config tokens and transforms etc, I just want my web.config file to be copied just like any other file. How do I achieve that? I've seen the `/p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False` method for the commad line but I'm not using the command line, I am using the GUI to create the package. How will I stop web.config from changing the connection string to a token?

And before you say: Yes, I know that I can copy the original web.config from my original directory, but I don't want to deal with this and that, I want to finish it with a single click as I'm testing the publish package and frequently re-creating the package.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have to edit your .csproj file and in the Debug PropertyGroup you'll have to add the following:

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

I have the following on **Release** and **ReleaseCERT** Configurations in my Project.csproj (I've only added the AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings line):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '**Release**|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <!-- add the following line to avoid ConnectionString tokenization -->
    <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '**ReleaseCERT**|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <!-- add the following line to avoid ConnectionString tokenization -->
    <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - any idea *why* we have to do this?

Comment: @Mustafakidd it's related to the msdeploy packaging invoked during whenever you build your project (using MSBuild). The ReplacableToken should be replaced only when deploying (using the TransformXml task in your .csproj/.vsproj. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750153/transforming-files-with-msdeploy)

Comment: An easier solution might be to add a dummy conn string transform to the Web.Debug.config or Web.Release.config.

Comment: @Justin the token appears exactly when you have a ConnectionString, in the original Web.config or in one of the transforms (Web.Debug.config, Web.Release.config, etc). In my case, I had different ConnectionStrings for each transform configuration.

Comment: You can also keep this setting in your pubxml file

Answer (score 17):

I had to do what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586546/1037948) said, but instead in the `Properties/PublishProfiles/__THEPROFILE__.pubxml` file rather than the `.csproj` file.

*(this may because I'm using VS2012?)*

Comment: Same thing for VS 2015.

Comment: Same thing for VS 2017.

Comment: Same thing for VS 2019

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when I was trying to create a web project package externally for a **WiX** setup according to the [Travis Illig instructions](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/07/30/how-to-consume-msdeploy-staged-web-site-output-in-a.aspx/). I solved it by adding the `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False` to the `MSBuild/@Properties`:

```
<MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.FullPath)"
         Targets="Package"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=AnyCPU;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False"
         Condition="'%(ProjectReference.WebProject)'=='True'"
```

Comment: +1 This is the appropriate solution for this particular case, as it doesn't involve tinkering with the config of the deployed project, only the deployment logic.

Answer (score -2):

I had to add the following in the `Release` condition section of my `Project.csproj` file:

```
<InsertAdditionalWebCofigConnectionStrings>False</InsertAdditionalWebCofigConnectionStrings>
```

Comment: Didn't fix the issue.  I think that the XML tag you provided may be misspelled.  Seems like it should be spelled like this...

InsertAdditionalWebConfigConnectionStrings, not InsertAdditionalWebCofigConnectionStrings

Either way, this didn't work for me.